# Jquery submit incl. file upload in IE8

Tags: jquery, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, submit

Any suggestions? It works in other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari... 
Im looking for the Solution since days :(

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#formone').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#formone").validationEngine('validate')) {
        var data = new FormData(this);
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#indoc')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'getitall.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href = "index.php";
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

I'd be happy for any Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support ajax file upload, so you have to polyfill it.
A simple one is submitting the form containing the file with the result being loaded in an iframe

```
<form id="formone" target="iframe" method="post" action="getitall.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
</form>
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

```
$('#iframe').on('load', function(){
    var $body = $(this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow);
    if (!$body.is('body')){
        $body = $body.find('body');
    }
    var data = $body.html(); 
    // do something with the data   
});
```

Comment: Tricky :)
Im gonna try this tomorrow and will state my progress then. Thanks so far.

Comment: Works great, i just modified a bit for my use. Thanks a lot, youre the man! :)